# Toastr color doesn't change even when I have it in my CSS

Tags: javascript, toastr

I have the following in my scripts.js

```
toastr.options = {
    "closeButton": false,
    "debug": false,
    "newestOnTop": false,
    "progressBar": false,
    "positionClass": "toast-bottom-full-width",
    "preventDuplicates": false,
    "onclick": null,
    "showDuration": "300",
    "hideDuration": "1000",
    "timeOut": "0",
    "extendedTimeOut": "1000",
    "showEasing": "swing",
    "hideEasing": "linear",
    "showMethod": "fadeIn",
    "hideMethod": "fadeOut"
    }
    toastr.info(`Right Number ${rightGuessString}. Game Over.`);
```

and in my CSS

```
.toast-info {
  background-color: rgb(140, 71, 71);
}
```

However, this doesn't work. The toast always displays blue. What am I missing?

Comment: Try to check in the browser which style it's been applied, maybe the library applies the CSS with higher specificity elements
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_specificity.asp

Comment: FWIW...I added !important and it started to work :)